# Как заменить ссылку на картинку

Tags: jquery, css, css3, bxslider

Есть вот такая библиотека [jquery bx-slider](http://bxslider.com/examples/custom-next-prev-selectors)

На странице по [той же ссылке](http://bxslider.com/examples/custom-next-prev-selectors), разбирается пример как сделать кастомные переключатели слайдов. Делаю все как по примеру, только добавляю свои классы для стилей "prevstyle" "nextstyle" пытаюсь c помощью css задать картинки как фон, изменить размер, но ничего не выходит. Может кто-нибудь знает как сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  nextSelector: '#slider-next',
  prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
  nextText: ' ',
  prevText: ' '
});
```

```css
#slider-next a{
  background: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/V/1/Z/A/h/U/left-arrow-right-hi.png);
  background-size:cover;
  display:inline-block;
  height:60px;
  width:38px;
}
#slider-prev a{
  background: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Z/n/k/Z/y/j/left-arrow-gray-hi.png);
  background-size:cover;
  display:inline-block;
  height:60px;
  width:38px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com//images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com//images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com//images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

<div class="outside">
  <h3>This div is outside of the slider</h3>
  <p><span id="slider-prev"></span><span id="slider-next"></span></p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: да, это то что мне нужно! спасибо большое!

Comment: Вообще говоря, есть гораздо более интересные современные слайдеры. Я бы советовал юзать:

http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WT5da-uLSUk

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

В этих богатое апи и поддержка мобильных устройств. А вашу 
галерею и самим легко написать за 15 минут на чистом js.

Comment: спасибо за рекомендацию!